# При изменении переменной меняется и аргумент в lambda python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, lambda

Я получаю информацию из файла, а потом вызываю функцию `select_user`.
Вот упрощённая версия кода:

```py
from tkinter import * # Использую tkinter для графического интерфейса

a_txt = open("a.txt", encoding = "utf8").read() # Читает файл a.txt
a = {}
for i in a_txt.split("\n"): # При каждой строке файла выполняет следующее
    a_tab = a.split("\t")
    a[a_tab[0]] = a_tab[1] # Обнаруживая таб в файле, разделяет его на две части и записывает в a

tk = Tk()

def select_user(clid):
    print(clid)

for name, clid in a.items():
    b = Button(tk, text = name, command = lambda: select_user(clid)) # Создаёт кнопку
    b.place(relx = 0.034, rely = 0.08) # Размещает кнопку на экране (в оригинальном коде они помещаются на экран в разные места)
```

Вот файл **a.txt** (вместо четырёх пробелов там табы):

```
Название1    0
Название2    1
Название3    2
```

Проблема заключается в том, что аргумент `clid` изменяется с каждой итерацией `for` и при нажатии кнопки передаётся самый последний результат.
Вот результат нажатия на 3 разные кнопки:

```
2
2
2
```

Есть ли возможность как-нибудь по другому вызвать функцию с аргументом (и чтобы аргумент не менялся) при нажатии кнопки в `tkinter`?

Надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на первую кнопку чтобы результатом был `0`, на вторую `1`, а на третью `2`

Comment: Кст, вместо `a_txt.split("\n")` лучше использовать `a_txt.splitlines()`

Comment: Хорошо, буду использовать `splitlines()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это поведение особенность лямбд при циклах. Чтобы обойти проблему нужно в лямбде значение задавать как параметр с значением, поэтому вместо `lambda: select_user(clid)` нужно писать `lambda clid=clid: select_user(clid)` (т.е. мы объявили лямбду с параметром `clid`, у которого значение по-умолчанию берется из переменной `clid`)

Пример:

```
b = Button(tk, text = name, command=lambda clid=clid: select_user(clid))
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает!

Comment: @Werryx, пожалуйста :)